# How to Access internet with IPhone without Wifi but with USB only?

Tags: iphone, internet, wireless-networking

I have a computer and it has a very strong internet connection. I don't have wifi for my wife prohibits it. How can I access internet in IPhone without wifi?

Comment: Stick a wifi router in the wall somewhere that doesn't advertise the SSID... your wife'll never know and it'll "just work". [j/k :) ] (In general, this kind of question should go to superuser or to the Mac OS X specific admin/user-help site.)

Comment: @Jim Thio emancipate!

Comment: Why does your wife prohibit the use of WIFI but would allow the use of your mobile phone to access the internet.  Its pretty much the samething.

Comment: @Ramhound, tell that to my wife yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a phone - buy a data plan. Or if you're going to be within cable range of the computer anyway, just use the computer!